# Failure to find project in Maven repository

Tags: maven

I have a Maven module with a submodule.

The relevant part of the parent is this:

```
  <groupId>my.package.name</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>my.package.name</name>

  <modules>
      <module>child-module</module>
  </modules>
```

The relevant part of the child is:

```
      <groupId>my.package.name</groupId>
      <artifactId>child-module</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
      <name>my.package.name</name>
    
      <parent>
          <groupId>my.package.name</groupId>
          <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- not necessary -->
      </parent>
```

For this, I'm getting:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for my.package.name:child-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find my.package.name:parent-module:pom:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project my.package.name:child-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/path/to/parent-module/child-module/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for my.package.name:child-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find my.package.name:parent-module:pom:1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

The XML files are located at:

```
/parent-module/child-module/pom.xml

/parent-module/pom.xml
```

So why is it trying to find the parne module in the online Maven repository?
Why doesn't see it locally?

Comment: "and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13". is says the relative path (your ../pom.xml) is wrong. paste in your question the structure of your project (directories)

Comment: I updated my question with the locations of the `pom.xml` files.

Comment: did u try to remove the "relativePath"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Failure to find my.package.name:parent-module:pom:1.0

Your parent version is `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>`, but in the child pom.xml parent version is `<version>1.0</version>` make it same

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute:

> mvn -U clean install

[Using Maven's -U Command Line Option](https://dzone.com/articles/using-mavens-u-command-line)

Comment: Now I get `[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for my.package.name:child-module:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact my.package.name:parent-module:pom:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 10, column 13
`

Comment: @octavian Remove `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` tag and try run again

Comment: @octavian I have a project with several submodules which of each is a Maven project and there is no usages of `</relativePath>`