# Build war with maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a local jar in my project and I can't do

```
mvn compile war:war
```

because I get this error:

> Failure to find myLib in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was
>   cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
>   -> [Help 1]

What do I need to add to the pom to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When maven says "resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of MyRepo has elapsed", where is that interval specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856307/when-maven-says-resolution-will-not-be-reattempted-until-the-update-interval-of)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca not at all, it seems like there is a local jar that is a non-maven dependency but is defined as such.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471392/failure-to-find-project-in-maven-repository

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the maven central repository on the internet.  The information is a bit vague so I would try all of these steps as a check, you may well have already done some.

Start by downloading maven from http://mirror.vorboss.net/apache/maven/maven-3/3.3.9/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.9-bin.zip

Unzip it somewhere, then assuming your're on windows

1) set an environment variable M2_HOME to point at the unziped folder.

2) add %M2_HOME%/bin to your PATH environment variable

3) go to your home directory (probably C:/Users/????? and create a .m2 folder

4) move the settings.xml file from the maven unzippped/conf directory to the directory created in step 3.

5) you may have to set the proxy element correctly in your settings.xml file (see [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for details)

Check all is working by doing:

```
greg@greg-XPS-13-9360:~/work/local-repo$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_161, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.4.0-112-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: that error is from a local library. it's not on the internet. it's in my project

Comment: if you're sure you can connect to the internet and maven central then blow away your ~/.m2/repo folder/myLib

Comment: dude that lib is not on the maven repo

Comment: The error says that you are trying to load a dependency called myLib from maven central, so of course it's not there, so your local repo adds some place holder files to stop it keep asking maven, I think you need to check your whole set up.